# Behavior of `with-temp-file' with `org-map-entries'

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

(2012-12-12 : edited to clarify the issue

- added symptoms description
- clarified the variable definition of temp-file in the first piece of code)

I'm trying to get this code working. The idea is to apply org-map-entries to a new file created by "with-temp-file", and still within the "with-temp-file sexp:

```
(let ((temp-file (expand-file-name "test-tmp-sandbox.org" dir)))
  (with-temp-file temp-file
    (insert-file (expand-file-name "my-org-file.org" dir))
    (org-mode)
    (org-map-entries '(org-entry-put nil "MY-READ-ONLY" ?t) t 'file)))
```

It does not work.

- no crash : OK
- the temp file is created and filled : OK
- when I open the file manually, the file is in org-mode, the org-headings are OK
- but the function org-entry-put that I want to map with org-map-entries is not applies *as if there were no org-entries, and indeed there are several* or *may be (org-mode) is not applied*

I've the following work-around :

```
(let ((temp-file (expand-file-name "test-tmp-sandbox.org" dir)))
  (with-temp-file temp-file
    (insert-file (expand-file-name "my-org-file.org" dir)))
  (find-file temp-file)
  (org-map-entries '(org-entry-put nil "MY-READ-ONLY" ?t) t 'file)
  )
```

which :

- get the file filled : OK
- get the mapping done : OK
- but is awkward !

Any idea what is going wrong with the first piece of code ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not say what "does not work". Always describe the symptoms: what you expected vs what you in fact saw.
2. Wrap your code in `(macroexpand '...)`, and you will see what is wrong: `temp-file` is undefined.

```lisp
 (let
     ((temp-file temp-file) ; TEMP-FILE on the right is undefined 
      (temp-buffer
       (get-buffer-create
        (generate-new-buffer-name " *temp file*"))))
   (unwind-protect
       (prog1
           (with-current-buffer temp-buffer
             (insert-file
              (expand-file-name "my-org-file.org" dir))
             (org-mode)
             (org-map-entries
              '(org-entry-put nil "MY-READ-ONLY" 116)
              t 'file))
         (with-current-buffer temp-buffer
           (write-region nil nil temp-file nil 0)))
     (and
      (buffer-name temp-buffer)
      (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))
```

---

**UPDATE**

Without looking into what `org-map-entries` is or does (no time; sorry), I'd suggest this: `with-temp-file` does not write the file until it finishes.  If `org-map-entries` expects the file to already exist (i.e., be written), then that would explain why your first code could not work.

Again, looking into what `org-map-entries` really does and expects will likely get you closer to a good answer, if what I said is not sufficient.

Comment: "You do not say what "does not work". Always describe the symptoms: what you expected vs what you in fact saw." Well you are 100% right ! And in teh present case, this would indeed have helped to explain : I have no issue with "temp-file being undefined, as it is defined elsewhere. Sorry for my poor explanation of the issue. So, to get that right, the symptoms are :

Comment: (continued) the symptoms are :
- (again : no issue with the variable "temp-file", sorry for being not clear on that in my first message)
- no crash
- but the function '(org-entry-put...) I want to map with org-map-entries is not applied, just as if there were no entry
- the second piece of code works

And thanks for the tip with macroexpand that I didn't know ! (new to lisp)